# Running tasks in a random order in airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Currently I have a list of tasks that all need to run at the same time every day, however they are all independent of one another. I know I can set them to run in a certain order i.e. `t1 >> t2 >> t3`, however I would like the order to be random so the order they finish isn't always the same. How can I run a list of airflow tasks in a random order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just said that they are independent of each other, why don't you just run them all at the same time?

[image]

This can be achieved by simply not using any shift operators, e.g:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(0)
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='example_random_task', default_args=args, max_active_runs=0, catchup=False)

first_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='{}_operator'.format("first"), dag=dag)
second_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='{}_operator'.format("second"), dag=dag)
third_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='{}_operator'.format("third"), dag=dag)
```

But if you really want to have random order of tasks and make them executable in some kind of random queue, you can add all your tasks to a list and them just shuffle. Then iterate over tasks and make current depended by the next one, for example:
[image]

To do so, use `random.shuffle()` which shuffles list in-place:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
import random

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(0)
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='example_random_task', default_args=args, max_active_runs=0, catchup=False)

first_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='{}_operator'.format("first"), dag=dag)
second_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='{}_operator'.format("second"), dag=dag)
third_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='{}_operator'.format("third"), dag=dag)

tasks_list = [first_operator, second_operator, third_operator]
random.shuffle(tasks_list)

i = 0
while i < len(tasks_list) - 1:
    tasks_list[i] << tasks_list[i + 1]
    i += 1
```

Have fun!